# Mapbox disabled user location tracking on camera pan

Tags: android, mapbox

I have recently been trying to find a way to allow users to go from being locked into `MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW` to `MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_NONE` if they try to pan the camera.

In essence I am hoping to implement functionality similar to Google Maps "Free roam" and "Recenter" features. However I have had a bit of trouble detecting when the user is attempting to pan the camera when in TRACKING_FOLLOW mode.

I have tried using `mapboxMap.getTrackingSettings().setDismissLocationTrackingOnGesture(true);` however it seems that using this the location tracking is disabled as soon as I set the location tracking to TRACKING_FOLLOW - without any user input (Perhaps the auto-rotation from using TRACKING_FOLLOW is triggering gestures). I also assume that this disables location tracking on all gestures zoom, rotation, panning, etc - rather than just when the user starts panning the camera.

I am sure that I am missing something very obvious but I was wondering if anyone who has an idea on how to achieve this functionality could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine if the user is in `TRACKING_FOLLOW` mode or not, you can run a check inside an `onMapScroll` listener and if they aren't in tracking then display your "recenter" button. Does this answer your question or am I not understanding the issue correctly?

Comment: Hey Cammace, this looks like exactly what I am looking for. However I have been having a hard time figuring out how add an OnMapScroll listener to MapView or mapviewMap. Do I need to extend MapView to override OnMapScroll?